# R - sequence with increasing interval

Tags: r, sequence

normal sequences with fixed intervals can be created using `seq(from, to, by= )`

is there a way to create a sequence with increasing intervals like the sequence below.

```
seq1 = c(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192)
```

here each of vector element is `2^index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use

```
## not `2 ^ 1:13`
2 ^ (1:13)
```

or

```
2 ^ seq(1, 13, 1)
```